# Need help making a random math generator

Tags: java, netbeans

What I am supposed to do is this:Write a program that gives the user 10 random math problems, asks for the answer each time, and then tells the user if they were right or wrong.  Each problem should use 2 random numbers between 1 and 20, and a random operation (+, -, *, or /).  You will need to re-randomize the numbers for each math problem.   You should also keep track of how many problems they get right.   At the end, tell the user how many problems they got right and give them a message based on their result.  For example, you may say “good job”  or “you need more practice.”

So far I am at a loss

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class SS_Un5As4 {

 public static void main(String[] args){

 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

 int number1 = (int)(Math.random()* 20) + 1;

int number2 = (int)(Math.random()* 20) + 1;

 int operator = (int)(Math.random()*4) + 1;

  if (operator == 1)

  System.out.println("+"); 

 if (operator == 2) 

   System.out.println("-");

 if (operator == 3)

 System.out.println("*");

  if (operator == 4)
            System.out.println("/");  


      }
  }
```

I mostly need to know how to turn these random numbers and operators into a problem, and how to grade each question to see if they are wrong.

Comment: What have you tried in that regard? I would say you have the hardest part done..

Comment: There seems to be something I am missing, but I just don't know how to do it. If you could elaborate that would be awesome.

Comment: print out <number1> <operator> <number2> = ?. Read in the user input. Check the answer and output the message. You might want to try to split into functions. You can also store the operators in `String operators = " +-*/"`. You can lookup and print from there..

Answer (score 4):

Well, what you need to add is:

- **to count answers**:

  - a variable that counts correct answers (increment it every time the user answers correctly);
  - a variable to store current **correct** answer;
  - a variable to store current user answer (refresh it every next problem, no need to store it forever, cause in your case only statistics is needed);
  - a function (let it be called e.g. gradeTheStudent() ) which uses several conditions to decide what to print out according to number of correct answers;
- **to create a problem**:

  - put problem generation and answer evaluation into a cycle, which repeats 10 times;
  - in your switch (i.e. when you choose operators) also calculate the correct answer:

    ```
     switch(operator){

          case 1: {
          operation = "+";
          correctResult = number1 + number2;
          break;
       }
       case 2: ....
       case 3: ....
       case 4: ....
       default: break;
    }
    ```
  - don't forget to check if the user entered a number or something else (you could use either an Exception or a simple condition).

So, a "pseudocode"solution for your problem would look something like this:

```
  String[] reactions = ["Awesome!","Not bad!","Try again and you will get better!"]
  num1 = 0
  num2 = 0
  operator = NIL
  userScore = 0
  userAnswer = 0
  correctAnswer = 0

  def function main:

      counter = 0
      for counter in range 0 to 10:
          generateRandomNumbers()
          correctAnswer = generateOperatorAndCorrectAnswer()
          printQuestion()
          compareResult()

      gradeStudent()

  def function generateRandomNumbers:
      # note that you have already done it!

  def function generateOperatorAndCorrectAnswer:
      # here goes our switch!
      return(correctAnswer);

  def function printQuestion:
      print  "Next problem:" + "\n"
      print num1 + " " + operator + " " + num2 + " = " + "\n"

  def function compareResult(correctAnswer):
      # get user result - in your case with scanner
      if(result == correctAnswer) 
                print "Great job! Correct answer! \n"
                userScore++
      else print "Sorry, answer is wrong =( \n"

  def function gradeStudent (numOfCorrectAnswers):
      if(numOfCorrectAnswers >= 7) print reactions[0]
      else if(numOfCorrectAnswers < 7 and numOfCorrectAnswers >= 4) print reactions[1]
      else print reactions[2]
```

**General advice:** don't try to solve the problem all at once. A good approach is to create small functions, each doing its unique task. The same with problem decomposition : you just should write down what you think you need in order to model the situation and then do it step by step.

**Note:** as far as I can see from your current function, you are not familiar with object oriented programming in Java. This is why I am not providing any tips about how great it would be to use classes. However, if you are, then please let me know, I will add info to my post.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

For example you can use something like that:

```
public class Problem {
    private static final int DEFAULT_MIN_VALUE = 2;
    private static final int DEFAULT_MAX_VALUE = 20;

    private int number1;
    private int number2;
    private Operation operation;

    private Problem(){
    }

    public static Problem generateRandomProblem(){
        return generateRandomProblem(DEFAULT_MIN_VALUE, DEFAULT_MAX_VALUE);
    }

    public static Problem generateRandomProblem(int minValue, int maxValue){
        Problem prob = new Problem();
        Random randomGen = new Random();

        int number1 = randomGen.nextInt(maxValue + minValue) + minValue;
        int number2 = randomGen.nextInt(maxValue + minValue) + minValue;

        prob.setNumber1(number1);
        prob.setNumber2(number2);

        int operationCode = randomGen.nextInt(4);
        Operation operation = Operation.getOperationByCode(operationCode);
        prob.setOperation(operation);

        return prob;
    }

    public int getNumber1() {
        return number1;
    }

    public int getNumber2() {
        return number2;
    }

    public Operation getOperation() {
        return operation;
    }

    public void setNumber1(int number1) {
        this.number1 = number1;
    }

    public void setNumber2(int number2) {
        this.number2 = number2;
    }

    public void setOperation(Operation operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }
}
```

And another class for holding operations:

```
public enum Operation {
    PLUS,
    MINUS,
    MULTIPLY,
    DIVIDE;

    public double operationResult(int n1, int n2) {
        switch (this) {
            case PLUS: {
                return (n1 + n2);
            }
            case MINUS: {
                return n1 - n2;
            }
            case MULTIPLY: {
                return n1 * n2;
            }
            case DIVIDE: {
                return n1 / n2;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Behavior for operation is not specified.");
    }

    public static Operation getOperationByCode(int code) {
        switch (code) {
            case 1:
                return PLUS;
            case 2:
                return MINUS;
            case 3:
                return MULTIPLY;
            case 4:
                return DIVIDE;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Operation with this code not found.");
    }
}
```

But you not must throw IllegalArgumentException, there are another options for handling unexpected arguments.

Comment: Perfect answer, in case the OP really understands OOP. +1

Answer (score 0):

Printout the numbers and the operation , read the user input using file IO , and perform your logic of keeping a track of answered questions
Code :

```
public class SS_Un5As4 {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number1 = (int)(Math.random()* 20) + 1;
        int number2 = (int)(Math.random()* 20) + 1;
        int operator = (int)(Math.random()*4) + 1;
        String operation = null;
        if (operator == 1)
            operation="+";      
        if (operator == 2) 
                operation="-";  
        if (operator == 3)
            operation="*";  
        if (operator == 4)
            operation="/";    
        System.out.println("Question "+number1+operation+number2);


    }
}
```

Keep a track of result and compare with the user input and verify its right or wrong

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

```
    int number1 = (int)(Math.random()* 20) + 1;
    int number2 = (int)(Math.random()* 20) + 1;
    int operator = (int)(Math.random()*4) + 1;
    String operation = null;
    int result=0;
    if (operator == 1){
        operation="+";
        result=number1+number2;
    }
    if (operator == 2) {
        operation="-";
        result=number1-number2;
    }
    if (operator == 3){
        operation="*";  
        result=number1*number2;
    }
    if (operator == 4){
        operation="/";
        result=number1/number2;
    }
    System.out.println("Question "+number1+operation+number2);
    String result1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();
    if(result==Integer.parseInt(result1))
        System.out.println("Right");
    else
        System.out.println("Wrong");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I pretty much know how to do it, I can get the all the questions to pop up and the person can answer them, but I'm still confused on how to record whether they are right or not.

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not want to hand you a full solution to this problem, and you seem to have some knowledge in the Java language I will just write down how I would continue/change what you have as a start.

First I would store the result in your operator if statements. Result is an int.

```
if (operator == 1) {
   operation="+";
   result=number1+number2;
}
```

After this I would print the math question and wait for the user to answer.

```
System.out.println("What is the answer to question: " +number1+operation+number2);
userResult = in.nextLine();      // Read one line from the console.
in.close(); // Not really necessary, but a good habit.
```

At this stage all you have to do is compare the result with the user input and print a message.

```
if(Integer.parseInt(userResult) == result) {
  System.out.println("You are correct!");
} else {
  System.out.println("This was unfortunately not correct.");
}
```

This solution is more or less psudo code and some error handling (if user enters test in the answer for example) is missing, also I would split it up into methods rather than have it all in main(). Next step would be to make it object oriented (Have a look at the answer from demi). Good luck in finalizing your program.

Answer (score 0):

```
In regard to generating random math operations with +, -, * & / with random numbers your can try the following;


import java.util.*;
public class RandomOperations{
   public static void main(String[] args){

       Random `mathPro` = new Random();
       //for the numbers in the game
       int a = mathPro.nextInt(50)+1;
       int b = mathPro.nextInt(50)+1;

       //for the all the math operation result

       int add = a+b;
       int sub = a-b;
       int mult = a*b;
       int div = a/b;
       //for the operators in the game

       int x = mathPro.nextInt(4);

       /*
         -so every random number between 1 and 4 will represent a math operator

         1 = +
         2 = -
         3 = x
         4 = /

      */

       if(x == 1){

          System.out.println("addition");
          System.out.println("");
          System.out.println(a);
          System.out.println(b);
          System.out.println(add);

       }else if(x == 2){

          System.out.println("subtraction");
          System.out.println("");
          System.out.println(a);
          System.out.println(b);
          System.out.println(sub);

       }else if(x == 3){

          System.out.println("multiplication");
          System.out.println("");
          System.out.println(a);
          System.out.println(b);
          System.out.println(mult);

       }else{

          System.out.println("division");
          System.out.println("");
          System.out.println(a);
          System.out.println(b);
          System.out.println(div);

       }
  //This os for the user to get his input then convert it to a numbers that the program can
  //understand
       Scanner userAnswer = new Scanner(System.in);
               System.out.println("Give it a try");
                 int n = `userAnswer.nextInt();
```